# Upper Bound for 2nd Raw Moment of Positive Random Variable

Tags: probability-inequalities, moment-generating-function, bounds

Let $X$ be a random variable with support $(0,\infty)$.  All I know about $X$ is the support, finite higher moments, and $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mu$.  I am trying to come up with a more tractable upper bound on $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$.  So far I have

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\int_0^\infty 2x P(X\geq x) dx$$
$$\leq\int_0^\infty 2x \underset{t>0}{\text{ min }} e^{-tx}M_X(t) dx$$

$$=\underset{t>0}{\text{ min }}\frac{2\times M_X(t)}{t^2}.$$

I do not know what $M_X(t)$ is though, though I know it exists and the first raw moment.  If $X$ were bounded, there are useful inequalities, but does anyone know how to do this minimization, or know an upper bound for $M_X(t)$ for random variables with positive support?

Comment: Conditional on knowing only the first raw moment, the second raw moment could be anything larger than the squared raw moment--and can even be infinite.  Thus there's no useful upper bound.